# Trouble with establishing my board for a game of connect four. How do I ralse the abstraction?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm having a hard time understanding the logistics of how to set up my board for a game of connect four. The board I made is obviously way to complicated, so can anyone give me tips or alternatives with handling this?

```
print("CONNECT FOUR ☼ ○")
first_row = [". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". "]
second_row = [". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". "]
third_row = [". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". "]
fourth_row = [". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". "]
fifth_row =[". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". "]
sixth_row = [". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". "]
seventh_row = [". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". ", ". "]


def display_board(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    print(a[0], a[1], a[2], a[3], a[4], a[5], a[6])
    print(b[0], b[1], b[2], b[3], b[4], b[5], b[6])
    print(c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3], c[4], c[5], c[6])
    print(d[0], d[1], d[2], d[3], d[4], d[5], d[6])
    print(e[0], e[1], e[2], e[3], e[4], e[5], e[6])
    print(f[0], f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5], f[6])
    print("1  2  3  4  5  6  7 ")

display_board(first_row, second_row,third_row, fourth_row, sixth_row, seventh_row)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would keep it as a single list that has multiple sub-lists:

```
board = [["."] * 7 for _ in range(7)]

def display_board(board):
    for row in board:
        print("  ".join(row))
    print("  ".join(str(num) for num in range(1, len(row) + 1)))

display_board(board)
```

Then to access the top left cell, for example, you could do `board[0][0]`. To access the third item in the fourth row, it would be `board[3][2]`.

Comment: Thank you for this recommendation, I will definitely use this. The only question I have is how would I get the columns of dots to align with the numbers?

Comment: @EmilyRivas: Sorry, I missed that. You would need an extra space in the `"  ".join()` line in the `for` loop. I edited.

Comment: @EmilyRivas: Is something not working? (I noticed you un-accepted my answer.)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mean to do that. My bad